# Query to replace null values from the table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table like this,

**Current Table1**

```
id | car_name | model | year
---+----------+-------+----- 
1  |a         | abc   | 2000
2  |b         | xyx   | 2001
3  |null      | asd   | 2003
4  |c         | qwe   | 2004
5  |null      | xds   | 2005
6  |d         | asd   | 2006
```

as you can see i have some null values , i want to replace them with the previous row values.

So it should become like this

**Desired Table1**

```
id | car_name | model | year
---+----------+-------+----- 
1  |a         | abc   | 2000
2  |b         | xyx   | 2001
3  |b         | asd   | 2003
4  |c         | qwe   | 2004
5  |c         | xds   | 2005
6  |d         | asd   | 2006
```

I googled, but didn't find any solution for this.

Any suggestions always welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: What DBMS are you using? Is the previous row the one where id = current row.id-1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query should work even if there are several records in a row with `NULL`

Query:

**[SQLFIDDLEExample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/60cfd/1)**

```
UPDATE Table1
SET car_name = (SELECT t1.car_name
                FROM (SELECT * FROM Table1) t1
                WHERE t1.id < Table1.id
                AND t1.car_name is not null
                ORDER BY t1.id DESC
                LIMIT 1)
WHERE car_name is null
```

Result:

```
| ID | CAR_NAME | MODEL | YEAR |
--------------------------------
|  1 |        a |   abc | 2000 |
|  2 |        b |   xyx | 2001 |
|  3 |        b |   asd | 2003 |
|  4 |        c |   qwe | 2004 |
|  5 |        c |   xds | 2005 |
|  6 |        d |   asd | 2006 |
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
UPDATE Table1 as first
INNER JOIN Table1 as second
    ON second.id = first.id-1
SET first.car_name = second.car_name
WHERE first.car_name IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be better to do it via a script/program or even a stored proc rather than doing it plainly using sql since you get additional benefits of handling some of the corner cases (like what happens when there are two successive rows with null etc) and also since I assume its a one time job.